# Missed colors in Highcharts donut chart rendering

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a problem with the Highcharts Donut chart, with a big number of data.
The last colors are missed in the rendering. Moving the mouse on the blank areas the colors are shown.

http://jsfiddle.net/2t93vthq/

I've tried without the option
`plotOptions.pie.animate = false`
without success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you are using Highcharts's default color set which contains 10 different colors in default, and since your'e using an iterator as a color index, you'd expect getting `undefined` for some of the colors (in other words, from the 11th point).

Any way, you can always create your own color set :

```
var myColors = ['red','blue','yellow'....]
```

or maybe using a more "suffisticated" color generator that will create a color set for you (like this one which I just googled : http://www.paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/)

Or, if you'd like to stick to the pre-defined color set, you can use a differnt method for choosing a color for each iteration, such as using a 'circular' counter:

```
    var data=[];
    var currentColor = 0;
    for(i in d){

        data.push({
                y: d[i].perc,
                color: colors[currentColor],
                drilldown: {
                    name: d[i].label,
                    categories: d[i].disc_eti,
                    data: d[i].disc_perc,
                    color: colors[0]
                }
        });
        currentColor = currentColor < 9 ? currentColor + 1 : 0;
    }
```

which will promise that you won't be using missing colors.
http://jsfiddle.net/xw75je1h/1/